# Partition by binned column in peewee (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

Peewee describes how to aggregate data by partitioning:
http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#window-functions

E.g.

```
query = Sample.select(
Sample.counter,
Sample.value,
fn.AVG(Sample.value).over(partition_by=[Sample.counter]).alias('cavg'))
```

Is there a way to partition by a *binned* numeric column?
E.g. say you wanted to average every *two* `Sample.counter`s

I know `numpy.digitize` can do the binning for you:

```
np.digitize(range(0,10),range(0,10,2))
```

But how do I combine that with a `peewee` query?

This is essentially trying to create a histogram query :)

Comment: http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-histogram-summary-frequency-distribution.html

Comment: looks like `width_bucket` is a PostgreSQL-specific function. I'm using sqlite :/